# MySQL between query returning redundant results

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT webcal_entry.cal_id, webcal_entry.cal_name , webcal_entry.cal_priority,
webcal_entry.cal_date , webcal_entry.cal_time , webcal_entry_user.cal_status,
webcal_entry.cal_create_by , webcal_entry.cal_access, webcal_entry.cal_duration ,
webcal_entry.cal_description , webcal_entry_user.cal_category 
FROM webcal_entry, webcal_entry_user
WHERE webcal_entry.cal_date BETWEEN '20090601' AND '20090631'
```

When I execute that query php throws back:

```
mysql_query(): unable to save result set
MySQL client ran out of memory
```

When I limit the results I see that it is pulling some 2.8 million results back. This table has 7,241 rows.

I realize I could use LIKE, but I really don't want to go that route.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You are joining the `webcal_entry` and `webcal_entry_user` tables in your `FROM` clause but you do not have any `JOIN ON` or `WHERE` conditions constraining which rows from `webcal_entry_user` to return. The result will be the cartesian product of the two tables, which basically means you'll get back each `webcal_entry` row that has a valid `cal_date`, **multiplied** by the number of rows in the `webcal_entry_user` table.

In other words, if you `webcal_entry_user` has 400 rows you'll get back 400*7241 = 2.8 million rows! Yikes!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a [cartesian join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). Basically, for each row in the first table you're joining against all the rows in the second. If the first table has 4 rows and the second 10 the result set will have 40 (4x10)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the key you're joining on that exists in both tables to the WHERE clause. Something like:

```
AND   webcal_entry.user_id = webcal_entry_user.user_id
```